# Problem getting real IP in php

Tags: php

I am using this to get real IP but I take empty from `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`, I take not empty only from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` .But I dont need the IP of proxy, I need the real ip of computers using some intranet. Can I get it? When `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` does not return empty?

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: There's no way to get the "real IP" 100% of the time.

Comment: Be careful if you use the IP for anything important. Spoofing (falsifying) the IP to fool your app is trivially trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The functions on this page are not reliable.

The only reliable IP from `$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];`
Otherwise anyone could fake his IP address by sending the CLIENT_IP header for example.

[This Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) can help you send custom headers. Sending the CLIENT_IP=x.x.x.x header to a server running any of the functions on this page, would mean that clients can choose any IP they want...

Comment: Stated more explicitly, you cannot know if the REMOTE_ADDR you get is that of the end client or of an intermediate proxy and you cannot know if the X-Forwarded-For was added by a proxy or spoofed by the user. If you run your own reverse proxy in front of PHP, then you may be more safe in assuming that the **last** value in X-Forwarded-For was added by your own proxy. But you cannot write generic code that works whether you are behind a reverse proxy or not.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_CLIENT_IP is not specified in the `$_SERVER` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)...  It may be available as an [environmental variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) (under `$_ENV`), but it's not in `$_SERVER`.  The method you're using (going to `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, then falling back on `REMOTE_ADDR`) is about the best you can do...

Comment: This is a rather critical point to raise. Just testing this now, and in fact, HTTP_CLIENT_IP is not in our apache $_SERVER values, as you noted, correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is about all that you can do to get this information. I'm not 100% sure what you are saying, but try the 2 methods below to see if they give you different/better info.

Try:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers(); 
echo $headers['X-Forwarded-For'];
```

Or:

```
$ip_list = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
echo $ip_list;
```

Comment: only getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') returns ip of proxy
all the other:  getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
                getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
returns empty???

Comment: @leda: and the other suggestion: `$headers = apache_request_headers(); echo $headers['X-Forwarded-For'];` What does that return?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to resolve this 100% of the time, but this would get you about as close as possible:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) {
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) {
        $proxy = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    } else {
        $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
} else {
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
}

echo "IP resolved to: ".$ip." (could still be a proxy IP though)<br>";
if($proxy) echo "Proxied through: ".$proxy;
```

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is comma-space-separated.  So, your code has a bug in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is one of the best ways to get the real ip

by: oliver leuyim angel

```
function getRealIP(){
    if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '' ) { 
        $client_ip = ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] :(( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ? $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR'] : "unknown" );

        // los proxys van añadiendo al final de esta cabecera
        // las direcciones ip que van "ocultando". Para localizar la ip real
        // del usuario se comienza a mirar por el principio hasta encontrar
        // una dirección ip que no sea del rango privado. En caso de no
        // encontrarse ninguna se toma como valor el REMOTE_ADDR

        $entries = split('[, ]', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        reset($entries);
        while (list(, $entry) = each($entries)){
            $entry = trim($entry);
            if ( preg_match("/^([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)/", $entry, $ip_list) ){
                // http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html
                $private_ip = array(
                    '/^0./',
                    '/^127.0.0.1/',
                    '/^192.168..*/',
                    '/^172.((1[6-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))..*/',
                    '/^10..*/');
                $found_ip = preg_replace($private_ip, $client_ip, $ip_list[1]);
                if ($client_ip != $found_ip){
                    $client_ip = $found_ip;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $client_ip = ( !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : ( ( !empty($_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) ? $_ENV['REMOTE_ADDR'] : "unknown" );
        if ($client_ip == 'unknown') {
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
            {
                $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}
                elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
                {
                    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                }
                else { 
                    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                }
                $client_ip = $ip;
            }
        }
    return $client_ip;
}
```

Comment: This function is a little messy and contains some invalid logic - if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is empty, why check for it again later?

Comment: Also, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR returns IPv6 addresses for mobile networks (at least every current US based phone user I see while testing the values of real users at the moment), which further invalidates this technique, so you want to assume all mobiles accessing are going to show ipv6 addresses. Which means your internal systems have to be coded to support those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymizing proxies will not populate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or REMOTE_ADDR, or will populate them using their own IP addresses, not the client IP address.

If you are working on something where you absolutely must identify the ip address of the gateway the client computer is using and are having to deal with situations where anonymizing proxies are being used, then you will have to come up with something else. I have in the past, used flash to make a socket connection to the server and send a unique key provided to the flash via params.

Be aware though that this is not a perfect solution. But in the case I was using it, to prevent cheating on a voting app, it worked fine. No flash, no vote. Similar things could be done with Java applets, silverlight, etc. Any client tech where you can specify the port that you talk to the server with. You would not want to use 80, 8080, etc, any of the common proxy ports.