# how to store Dynamic IP Address using PHP

Tags: php, dynamic-ip

Get IP Address :

```
$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
```

Insert Into Mysql

```
$ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO smp_result SET point='$option',ip='$ip', tm='$id'");
```

Show the result :

```
$prog=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id' AND ip='$ip'");
```

but the stored IP Address is the IP Address of the ISP, what if I want to save the DHCP IP Address ??

Comment: Your server can _only_ see the public address of the client. Do you mean to say that you want to store the RFC 1918 address of a client behind a router or NAT for example?  Like a `10.0.0.1` or `192.168.1.1` address?

Comment: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063244/problem-getting-real-ip-in-php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's a harmful link actually